# Hex change low to high and then conever to decimal

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I have Hex string like 1480D604. Which I need to change order from Low to High 0x04D68014 and then I need to cast it into decimal value. One approach that I can think is first change their order first like.

Step 1 : 14-80-D6-04 --> 04-D6-80-14

How can I change this order from Low to High order in hex value.

Step 2

Cast output from first step into decimal value like this

int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

0x04D68014=81166356

Is there any simple way to achieve this in single step.

Comment: So `0x04D68014` is low to high order?

Comment: Yes data received at our end is in reverse order

Comment: FYI "decimal" means something else, you're talking about an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it in a "single step" is to define a method, use the [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static int ReverseByteOrder(int value)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
int value = 0x1480D604; //or parse from string
int decValue = ReverseByteOrder(value);
//decValue = 0x04D68014
```

## IsLittleEndian

Strictly speaking, you should look at [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian(v=vs.110).aspx) as it is possible that the order is already in the correct order, depending on the system it's running on.

This is very unlikely, so I wouldn't bother coding to that case, but I would at the very least cause the program to fall over if run on a system where `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is **not** `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by reversing a byte array. So first convert your string to byte array with this method:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
  int NumberChars = hex.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
  bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
}
```

Use like:

```
string hexString = "1480D604";
byte[] byteArray = StringToByteArray(hexString);
```

Then reverse the byte array:

```
Array.Reverse(byteArray);
```

Then convert it back to hex string again with the method:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

Using like:

```
string reversedString = ByteArrayToString(byteArray);
```

And finally convert it to `int` as you mentioned:

```
int decValue = int.Parse(reversedString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

And that's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't need to parse each individual character, you can use int.Parse and BitConverter.GetBytes, as shown in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx). Neither do you need to convert the byte array to string in order to get an int, BitConverter.ToInt32 will do this directly

Comment: True, there are shorter ways to achieve it, but this one also works. Was the first one which came to my mind...